# MYSQL bitwise OR over multiple entries

Tags: mysql, bit-manipulation

I need to update the status (bits) of a job depending on the status of all it's articles (also bits).

So for example I have a Job which has got the following articles

```
A: status = 1001
B: status = 1011
C: status = 0010
```

Now I want the job status to be = A OR B OR C = 1011.

Any way I can do this in MYSQL without having to make loops through all articles?

Thanks!

Comment: What format is the bit string stored in? Is is a 4 long bit field or a string of some kind?

For a 4 long bit you should be able to use BIT_OR aggregate function:-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many problems, it's a simple case of reading the documentation: [MySQL Bit Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html).

But let's get some things straight here. Are these values intended to be bitmasks? If that's the case (and I'm sure it is), then `B` is equal to `A | C`, which is a tad odd. Typically, bitmasks work in the following way...

```
A = 0001
B = 0010
C = 0100
...etc.
```

In this way, you can combine values and have the bitmask account for multiple options, so the combination of `A` and `C` (`A | C`) would be `0101`.

The whole purpose of a bitmask is that they can represent multiple values in a fixed-length string, so they're space efficient. The downside is that they don't make for human-readable output, unless you're used to looking at *The Matrix*!

On the other hand, I could be way off.

But, to get you going, I believe you are looking for the `BIT_OR` function: [MySQL GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-or), which calculates and returns the bitwise `OR` of all bits in `expr`.

Comment: I suspect that these are status fields on different rows (ie, one row per article). If so I suspect an aggregate function is required

Comment: I totally agree. I've used this in the past... but now I steer clear of bitmasks after several hours of trying to explain their value to silly bosses! :)

Comment: I am used to them from mainframe (PL/1) days but never really used them in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks! What I needed was BIT_OR. Saves me a lot of "looping arround time" :-) And lucky me, I won't need to explain anything to my Boss, as long it works ;-)
Cheers!